# SASS Stylesheet design patterns or other resources?

Tags: design-patterns, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

Can anyone recommend great resources (articles/books/blogs/etc.) for structuring **SASS stylesheets**? I understand syntax and how to use features like @mixin, @extend, etc. but I'm looking for guidance on how people approach the overall architecture of your stylesheet "system" for a large application.

I am using **Rails 3.1 with the asset pipeline**. I want to take maximum advantage of sass variables, mixins, etc. across several different sub-apps. These discreet sub-apps all need their own stylesheets but I want to keep everything as DRY as possible.

I hope my intent is somewhat clear without going into too much detail on the app. If not, I'll be happy to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to read [Scalable and modular architecture for CSS](http://smacss.com/book/). Basically this is techniques that can keep CSS more organized and more structured, leading to code that is easier to build and easier to maintain.

Comment: Best suggestion so far. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Best practices for Compass (CSS authoring framework that uses SASS):

http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/best_practices/